# Fstab Incorrect Bind Mount

Tags: mount, fstab

My (non-working) settings are below.

NOTE: The 2nd line works OK and the bind works. The problem is line 4th line. This just bricked my bootup & I had to chroot into my drive to # out line 4. I am simply trying to re-mount /export/raid as a read only filesystem. Why is my configuration not working?

```
#Create a bind-mount for /mnt/raidarray
/mnt/raidarray /export/raid     none    bind        0   0
#Remount /export/raid as read-only. 
/export/raid    /export/raid    none    remount,ro  0   0
```

NOTE: If I manually do this process on the terminal using the commands below it works. It's just the fstab entry I can't seem to get right.

```
$ sudo mount --bind /mnt/raiddrives/ /export/raid
$ sudo mount -o remount,ro /export/raid
```

Answer (score 2):

Your remount line is incorrect: you need to replace the first entry with the source rather than the destination and (I think) repeat the `bind` option:

```
/mnt/raidarray    /export/raid    none    remount,bind,ro  0   0
```

See this related U&L Q&A [Why doesn't mount respect the read only option for bind mounts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210885/65304)

---

For example, in `/etc/fstab`

```
192.168.1.127:/c/public /mnt/nas/public nfs defaults    0   0
/mnt/nas/public /mnt/nas/public-ro  none    bind        0   0
/mnt/nas/public /mnt/nas/public-ro  none    remount,bind,ro 0   0
```

then

```
$ sudo mount -a
$ 
$ grep nas /etc/mtab
192.168.1.127:/c/public /mnt/nas/public nfs rw,addr=192.168.1.127 0 0
/mnt/nas/public /mnt/nas/public-ro none ro,bind 0 0
```

And just to be sure

```
$ touch /mnt/nas/public/newfile
$ 
$ touch /mnt/nas/public-ro/newfile
touch: cannot touch ‘/mnt/nas/public-ro/newfile’: Read-only file system
```